# How would you implement a sorting mechanism for a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I know Stack Overflow isn't there to solve my problems, but to ask specific questions.
But I need to implement a sort function for a html table and have no idea how to do it.
The user should be able to click on the column header and the table should then be sorted by that column.
The table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: look in the sort() and use that with jquery advanced selector to do your work

Comment: I think Google would be helpful here. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/03/33-javascript-solutions-for-sorting-tables/

Comment: what sort? Is this a jquery function?

Comment: Do you need to write it yourself, or simply implement the functionality? There are many pre-existing solutions available for this: DataTables, jqGrid, TableSorter, etc

Comment: Have you already searched for existing solutions? Why don't you want to use them?

Comment: No need to use any JavaScript plugin. You can achieve this with just 20 lines of JavaScript code. Just [refer this article](http://www.funbutlearn.com/2013/04/create-interactive-html-tables-with.html) to get detail instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several plug-ins available works with jQuery. Try this one http://tablesorter.com

Add this library to your page like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<your-path>/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>`

apply the class called `tablesorter` to your table and say `$(".tablesorter").tablesorter();`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jquery, use datatables jquery plugin.It is a highly flexible tool

http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: +1 I love that tool; it's very flexible and customizable

Comment: Yes, its implementation is very easy and support a lot of much features.

Comment: But I wrote it from scratch just to add a single column :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jquery, you could use the [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) plugin to do that for you.

There are [many others](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/05/jquery-filter-sort-plugins.html) so do browse around and see which fits your use case the best.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [List.js](http://listjs.com/) cause

1. it's lightweight [only 3K script]
2. easy to implement in your existing HTML table using class
3. searchable, sortable and filterable

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-list">
    <ul class="list">
       <li>
           <h3 class="name">Luke</h3>
       </li>
       <li>
           <h3 class="name">John</h3>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var options = {
    valueNames: ['name']
};
var myList = new List('my-list', options);
```